# Unity Raycasting problem in some part of the scene

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I started doing some simple stuff in Unity (goal is to make a great game) so I made a simple Player Controller.

```
public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float walkingSpeed;
    public float jumpSpeed;
    public bool jumpFlag = false;
    public float maxJumpDistance = 1.0f;
    Rigidbody rb;
    Collider col;
    Vector3 playerSize;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
        col = GetComponent<Collider>();
        playerSize = col.bounds.size;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        WalkHandler();
        JumpHandler();
    }

    void WalkHandler()
    {
        float horizonstalAxis = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        float verticalAxis = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");
        Vector3 movement = new Vector3(-horizonstalAxis * walkingSpeed * Time.deltaTime, 0, -verticalAxis * walkingSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
        rb.MovePosition(transform.position += movement);
    }

    void JumpHandler()
    {
        float jumpAxis = Input.GetAxis("Jump");
        //Debug.Log(jumpAxis);
        if (jumpAxis > 0)
        {
            bool isGrounded = CheckGrounded();
            if (jumpFlag != true && isGrounded)
            {
                jumpFlag = true;
                Vector3 jumpVector = new Vector3(0, jumpSpeed * Time.deltaTime, 0);
                rb.AddForce(jumpVector, ForceMode.VelocityChange);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            jumpFlag = false;
        }

    }

    bool CheckGrounded()
    {
        Vector3 checkerPoint = transform.position + new Vector3(0, -playerSize.y / 2, 0);
        bool grounded = Physics.Raycast(checkerPoint, -Vector3.up, maxJumpDistance);
        return grounded;
    }
```

I came across a wierd problem. In some parts of the scene my method JumpHandler is not working. After reaching some z coordinates, the CheckGrounded returns False instead of True, even though the Raycast direction is set down.
Can anyone help?

Comment: Your `CheckGrounded` logic seems flawed. First of all, it should probably ignore `maxJumpDistance`, because that value is irrelevant to checking if the player is grounded. Second of all, you would usually start the ray from the exact middle downwards, using a max distance of the playerSize half plus a minor security buffer. So try e.g. `return Physics.Raycast(transform.position, -Vector3.up, playerSize / 2 + 0.05f);` (Another approach is to use actual collision checks of the character's capsule collider.) Good luck!

Comment: @PhilippLenssen thanks for the tips! I will try to redesign it.